# How to know user has spent time in other apps in android

Tags: android

I am new in android. Now I want to find out How much time a user spends in other apps. Is it possible to get the details ? if yes then how ? I got the list of apps after not getting the time between foreground or background app. But unable to fetch how much the user has spent time.

Comment: No you can't.. may be it is possible in rooted devices.

Comment: If you are develop custom firmware, you can go to ActivityStackSupervisor & add necessary methods. Otherwise - you can't.